# Problem in creating url string

Tags: iphone, xcode, url, nsurlconnection

```
    NSString *sttr=[[NSString alloc]init ];
    NSURL *jsonURL;
    NSString *strurl;

    sttr =@"|7 Harvard Drive, Plymouth, MA, 02360, |9121 SW 174th St., Miami, FL, 33157, |7 Harvard Drive, Plymouth, MA, 02360, |";
    NSLog(@"StringToSend=%@",sttr);
    strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=optimize:true%@&sensor=false&mode=driving",sttr];
```

But the when i debug then strurl is always nil .

Whats the issue here is due to spaces in the location name .How can i haandle that .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well @mrugen , it is your 54th question in SO..Still you dont know how to format a question..

Comment: Actually typed it in bit hurry that's why ,sorry for that..

Comment: You need to URL encode the location. Spaces are encoded as a "+" I believe.

Comment: I wonder that it doesn't crash as you promise initWithFormat more arguments than you actually pass.

Comment: yes it crashes at strurl line

Comment: all of you sorry for my mistake actually i didnt pass the first two paramaters in string that's why i was not able to create the url and many thansk for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the components of the string to individual strings and then pass it to the necessary url string.

Try this and see if it works

```
NSURL *jsonURL;
NSString *strurl;
NSString *sourceString = @"|7 Harvard Drive, Plymouth, MA, 02360, |9121 SW 174th St.";
NSString *destString = @"Miami, FL, 33157, |7 Harvard Drive, Plymouth, MA, 02360, |";
strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@ |&waypoints=optimize:true%@&sensor=false&mode=driving",sourceString,destString,@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",strurl);
```

Comment: change the `sourceString` and `destString` according to your needs.

Comment: @ 7KV7 sorry for my mistake actually i didnt pass the first two paramaters in string that's why i was not able to create the url and many thansk for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

From your code the strurl shouldn't be nil.

By the way: You have a memory leak because `@"some string"` gives you an autoreleased object and the memory you retained in `NSString *sttr=[[NSString alloc]init ];` is never released.

Answer (score 0):

Change ur code.

```
strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=optimize:true%@&sensor=false&mode=driving",sttr,sttr,sttr];
```

Comment: Didn't see that one. But is this the reason for a return value of nil?

Comment: i think widout the above LOC u'll get `EXEC BAD ACCESS`.

Comment: sorry for my mistake actually i didnt pass the first two paramaters in string that's why i was not able to create the url and many thansk for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use same number of "%@" and the variables your pass change your code something like this -

```
strurl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=optimize:true%@&sensor=false&mode=driving",sttr,destinationStr,anotherVar];
```

Also I am not getting why you have a "%@" here -

```
waypoints=optimize:true%@&s
```

if you are fetching contents from this url that may be nil you should encode the url string before creating a NSURL from it .. use this function -

```
-(NSString *) URLEncodeString:(NSString *) str
{

    NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];


    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake actually i didnt pass the first two paramaters in string that's why i was not able to create the url and many thansk for your inputs.

Comment: if you think that my answer or any other's answer help you in solving your problem then you should accept that answer. you can also upvote any answer to tell him that his answer helped to you!